# Rails Specific Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, routes, action

I know in rails i can say

```
resources :articles do
   post :something
end
```

but this would give the regular routes, plus :something, what if i wanted to specify only post :something, or what if wanted to exclude a particular resource, but keep the rest (in my case i am trying to kick out delete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
resources :articles, :except => :destroy do
   post :something
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use except

```
resources :articles, :except => [:destroy]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are right, but you should check the [Guide to Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created) (linked you to the section on restricting routes) for more information on what options are available.